# ERD Circular dependency efficiency

Tags: android, sql, sql-server, erd

I have a classroom management system that I have created. All was going well and queries can be performed fine. I was just wondering is it right to have a circular dependency. A lot of places say it is inefficient and can cause a few problems. 
Here is the ERD. Any ideas on making it more efficient or is this ok? 
[image]

Comment: There are more possible solutions, but I don't see a problem here, as long as you insert all the dependent data in one transaction, to avoid missing FK, or at least some of the dependencies are nullable

Answer (score 0):

There is no circular dependency in your design. A circular dependency is where A depends on B, B depends on C, C depends on A, etc. I can see right away looking at your design that Classes is in your "circle", but it does not depend on anything. It is close, but there is no circular dependency.

On the more general topic of "can the design be improved". As was mentioned in the comments, there are probably a number of things you could do, most of which depends on your particular business problem. If it's applicable, I would recommend things like making the relationship between Classes and Users a many to many using a linking table, I'd question why Worksheet it tied to Topic and not Classes, etc.